# By default, asterisk will generate a CDR for every finished call in database cdr table

Tags: asterisk

By default, asterisk will generate a CDR on every finished call into a database cdr table. i want asterisk to add record into database cdr table when the agent answered call.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you working with queue/agents - use queue_log

Options you are searching located in cdr.conf

https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/master/configs/samples/cdr.conf.sample

Answer (score 0):

I am intending that you are talking about queues. There is an option in cdr.conf, you can set "unanswered = no". But I think if you are using musiconhold(moh) then for most of the DID/TFN providers do not support early media so you have to answer the call first. 
You have to modify your dialplan to set the disposition to unanswered when the call is not answered by any agent. You can check the call when the call is exiting the queue if its queuestatus is "abandon" then set it to "unanswered".